# Specific information from ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have unique constraints on columns name and email and when ConstraintViolationException is throwing by JPA I need information which column was violated but I get only:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1501144724882,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [uk_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/add"
}
```

I use PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Post your query/statement

Comment: I save it by Spring JpaRepository using method save

Comment: it will be better if you add the code and database query in the question

Comment: I don't use sql query. I use Spring Data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you get DataIntegrityViolationException , for the constraint's name `uk_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7` check in db what is it constraint. First check in table where you try to add/save element. It's looks like auto generated constraint , so without access db it's hard to say what is this constraint for.